# React not re-rendering the component on setState even though state is being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So Here's my code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Typist from 'react-typist';
import SvgComponent from './mapComponent';
import {stateData} from '../shared/exampleData'; 
class Home extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        isHovered:false,
        active:"347",
        res_today:"29",
        new_today:"16",
        hoveredState:null
    }
}
changeOnHover = (stateCode) =>{
    console.log("HERE is whats inside ",stateCode,stateData[stateCode]);
    this.setState({
        hoveredState:stateData[stateCode],
        isHovered:true
    },()=>{
        console.log("mouse in",this.state)
    });
}
mouseOut = () =>{
    this.setState({
        isHovered:!this.state.isHovered
    },()=>console.log("After Mouse Out",this.state))
} 
render(){
    var isHovered = this.state.isHovered;
    return(
        <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-7 large-screen-text">
                <Typist>
                <div className="top-text">
                    <br/>
                    <h1>781 Districts. 26 States. 1 Stop for all Complaints</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="mid-text">
                    <br/>
                    <h1 className="">Register Your Complaints</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="bottom-text">
                    <br/>
                    <span>
                        {isHovered ? 
                        <h1>Active: {this.state.hoveredState.active} 
                            <small>(+{this.state.hoveredState.new_today})</small> 
                        </h1> 
                        : 
                        <h1>Active: {this.state.active} 
                            <small>(+{this.state.new_today})</small>
                        </h1>}
                    <br />
                    <h1>Resolved Today: {this.state.res_today}</h1>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </Typist>
                <div class="pie-chart">    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5">
                <div>
                    <SvgComponent changeOnHover={this.changeOnHover} mouseOut={this.mouseOut}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm making use of SVG Component to change state information on hover over the SVG figure.

Here is a portion of what the SVGComponent has :

```
function SvgComponent(props) {
 return (
  <svg
   xmlnsMapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
   xmlnsDc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlnsCc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlnsRdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlnsSvg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   viewBox="2 0 700 700"
   >
    <defs
     id="defs42" />
    <a onMouseOver={()=>props.changeOnHover("IN-AN")} onMouseLeave={()=>props.mouseOut()}>
     <path
      id="IN-AN"
      title="Andaman and Nicobar Islands"
      d="m 537.188,685.44148 -0.041,0.4695 0.768,0.30627 0.104,2.47542 1.258,1.84675 -0.71,-0.0232 
      0.661,0.93295 -0.574,0.18739 -0.437,0.94503 0.103,1.88201 -0.409,0.42617 -0.663,-0.49065,.. 
      ....,-0.62565 z" />
    </a>
    .
    .
    .
    </svg>);
  }
```

Now, According to the above mentioned code, it should work such that when mouse moves over the figure developed using the path tag in svg, the number displayed in active within Home must update. But it is not happening. I can see that the state is getting updated but there is not re-rendering happening.

Here is what stateData imported from exampleData contains:

```
export const stateData ={
"IN-AN": {
    active:"10",
    new_today:"68",
    res_today:"17"
},
"IN-AP":{
    active:"14",
    new_today:"45",
    res_today:"78",
},
"IN-TN":{
    active:"19",
    new_today:"87",
    res_today:"76",
},
"IN-KA":{
    active:"69",
    new_today:"69",
    res_today:"69",
},
"IN-KL":{
    active:"12",
    new_today:"13",
    res_today:"14",
  }
}
```

**Edit 1**: It was not updating because of the Typist Component I was using for animation. After I removed it, it worked fine.

Comment: Move your SVG Component inside the class, and render it with <this.SvgComponent/>. then, try this.changeOnHover("IN-AN") instead of props.changeOnHover() in the SVG Component. Same goes for mouseOut.

Comment: @TechySharnav your method as well is updating the state, but its not re-rendering.

Comment: Well in that case, try setting a state in ComponentDidMount. This force re-renders the component. Like, setInterval(()=>this.setState({func:True}), 2000), inside ComponentDidMount